# Example of a paged list - ASP .NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

What is the best way to page a model that contains a list?

As per model below, i wish to page through "Emails" on my Company Model. I am currently trying to achieve this with PagedList MVC.

Example Model

```
public class EmailModel
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string EmailMessage { get; set; }
    public Guid CompanyId { get; set; }
}

public class CompanyModel
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }
    public IPagedList<Email> Emails { get; set; }
}
```

My Page has a partial view to display the emails

```
@Html.Partial("_CompanyEmails.cshtml", Model.Emails);
```

Can someone show me an example of a controller to handle this?

Comment: @tere then also fix the title...

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into the [docs](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/sorting-filtering-and-paging-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application)?

About two thirds down the page is a heading for:

> Add Paging Functionality to the Index Method

---

## Controller

---

The sample given (in their context) is:

```
using PagedList;
...
...
public ViewResult Index(string sortOrder, string currentFilter, string searchString, int? page)
{
   ViewBag.CurrentSort = sortOrder;
   ViewBag.NameSortParm = String.IsNullOrEmpty(sortOrder) ? "name_desc" : "";
   ViewBag.DateSortParm = sortOrder == "Date" ? "date_desc" : "Date";

   if (searchString != null)
   {
      page = 1;
   }
   else
   {
      searchString = currentFilter;
   }

   ViewBag.CurrentFilter = searchString;

   var students = from s in db.Students
                  select s;
   if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
   {
      students = students.Where(s => s.LastName.ToUpper().Contains(searchString.ToUpper())
                             || s.FirstMidName.ToUpper().Contains(searchString.ToUpper()));
   }
   switch (sortOrder)
   {
      case "name_desc":
         students = students.OrderByDescending(s => s.LastName);
         break;
      case "Date":
         students = students.OrderBy(s => s.EnrollmentDate);
         break;
      case "date_desc":
         students = students.OrderByDescending(s => s.EnrollmentDate);
         break;
      default:  // Name ascending 
         students = students.OrderBy(s => s.LastName);
         break;
   }

   int pageSize = 3;
   int pageNumber = (page ?? 1);
   return View(students.ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize));
}
```

---

## View

---

If there are no pages to display, "Page 0 of 0" is shown. (In that case the page number is greater than the page count because Model.PageNumber is 1, and Model.PageCount is 0.)

The paging buttons are displayed by the PagedListPager helper:

```
@Html.PagedListPager( Model, page => Url.Action("Index", new { page }) )
```

Comment: Isn't this paging the whole model though? i.e. this would be the equivalent of paging the CompanyModel. I just want to page the Emails inside the CompanyModel

Comment: What you're looking for then is to return PartialView(...) instead of return View(...) as well as changing the Actionresult Name to something else